# How to read bit file mpeg video using java

Tags: java, video, filestream, readfile

as title.. how to read bit of file mpeg video using java..

I use it for encryption file video.

Regards

Comment: Please give more details. Is it MPEG-1 (.MPG) or MPEG-2 (.TS) or MPEG-4 (.MP4)? Do you get it encrrypted or you yourself do the encryption?

Comment: it is MPEG-1 (.MPG). i do encryption by myself.. thanks ya :)

Comment: If my answer does not help please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [PS container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_program_stream) if you are interested how the different (audio and video) streams are multiplexed to a single file.

Comment: I see the format of the header but what is the format of the frames that follow the header?  I assume there is some complicated interpolation that requires decoding.